# How would the technology of this advanced species work?

Tags: terraforming

I am writing a story where a moderately advanced race of aliens arrive on an earth-like planet and terraform it, even using technology to immediately create landforms. However, this only takes place in the prologue and the next chapter features a human scientist explaining to a group of students how the terraforming process occured.

My question is how would the process of immediately creating landforms be explained in a suitable and non-generic or vague way.

Comment: Welcome to the site GGWP, when you have a few minutes, please take the [tour] and read up in our [help] about how we work: [ask]. This seems to qualify as too story-based, what you seem to be asking about is a [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/what-is-narrative-necessity-and-how-does-it-apply-to-worldbuilding), which would be off-topic here. Refer to  the [help], you'll get the hang of the culture here.

Comment: [The pyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_pyramids). [Kurgans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurgan). The [Suez Canal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suez_Canal). The [Salton Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salton_Sea). A large part of the [Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polder#Netherlands). [Silbury Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silbury_Hill). The many [tells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tell_(archaeology)) of the ancient Near (= "Middle" in American) East. [Lake Nasser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Nasser). No alien technology required.

Comment: Hi GGWP.  I suspect this question isn't ready for prime time and could benefit from our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183).  As is, the question is either (a) downvotable for insufficient research (you can search online for terraforming ideas, requirements, and technologies) or (b) too broad in that you're asking us to invent an entire technology tree for you.  Stack Exchange's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).

Comment: Two questions worth pondering.  1) Why do you need a non-generic way.  [Sanderson's First Rule of Magic](https://brandonsanderson.com/sandersons-first-law/) works for sci-fi too, and saves a lot of trouble.  2) What do you mean by "immediately?"  Are we talking fractions of a second, years, or a million years (which is "immediate" on a geological scale)?

Comment: This is way too broad, can you specify?

Answer (score 0):

**Research into how the aliens accomplished their terraforming is still underway.**

The planet where this took place has been discovered by humans.  The aliens responsible are long gone or perhaps noncommunicative in their current state.  Humans are researching this planet and how it was molded, and understand the technology to varying degrees.

I could imagine landforms being molded by manipulating plate tectonics.  One could manipulate plate tectonics by manipulating currents of magma driving them from beneath.  You could manipulate magmatic flow by manipulating the electromagnetic forces of the planet interior.  The scientist can go on to say that this is the current hypothesis of how it was done, and given the short period and huge energies involved probably done first before subsequent terraforming was done.  How the aliens manipulated the electromagnetic fields of a planet core is still unknown but of course an active area of research.

He can go on to say that other aspects of the planet surface are better understood - certain mountains and one island chain are obviously composed of asteroids from the outer reaches of the system.  He can note that these metallic mountains although millions of years old are still measurably sinking into the crust year by year.  How they were brought in for soft landings on the planet surface is still not understood.